# How can I retrieve the date an issue was added to a projectV2 using Github's GRAPHQL api?

Tags: github, graphql

I'm working on a Github automation script, for a specific task I need to know from a projectV2 and an issue number, get the date when the issue was added using the graphQL api.

I tried projectcards but it concerns only the project item and not the projectV2. I tried to look at the REST Api but same, cannot found this informations.